# send email from PHP with outgoing mail server & userid and password authantication

Tags: php, email

what is best way to send email from PHP using server authantication.

Userid & Password & outgoing mail server...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a library like one of the following:

- SwiftMailer
- phpMailer
- Zend_Mail

Answer (score 3):

Use the PEAR Mail module.  See [the PHP: mail documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#39305).

Comment: Note that the link is to a specific comment on the page, about the PEAR module `Mail::`, which provides the functionality about which the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

[Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.smtp-authentication.html) supports SMTP authentication

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways, it really depends how your scripts works. More info would be helpful. But you could just create a method that accepts the userid and password, validate the user against your database, and, if true send the email.

Comment: Hes probably trying to send specifically with a certain SMTP account so i dont think this is really a potential solution.